# How many different universes do the episodes of the 1995 Outer Limits occur in?

Tags: continuity, the-outer-limits

As far as I remembered episodes of The Outer Limits (the 1995 relaunch) had no continuity, but I was just reading [the Wikipedia page for The Sandkings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandkings) and noticed this section mentioning later references to the events of this episode:

> **Aftermath** The Sandkings thrived after their escape from Kress'
>   home laboratory. Fragments from the episode are included in the final
>   episode of season one, "The Voice of Reason". There, clips from "The
>   Sandkings" are used to support an argument that the Earth is
>   undergoing a number of different alien invasions. Later in the
>   episode, two alien conspirators acknowledge, in private conversation,
>   that the Sandkings could become a serious problem in about thirty
>   years, assuming that they could survive in a methane-based atmosphere,
>   which the aliens intended to gradually transform from the Earth's
>   human-friendly one.
>
> In the sixth-season episode "Final Appeal", we discover that the
>   Sandkings plague has been eradicated, which took "the better part of a
>   decade" to complete.

I then noticed that [the episode "A Special Edition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Special_Edition) apparently includes clips from, or references to, multiple other episodes: "Last Supper", "New Lease", "Blood Brothers", "The Voice of Reason", "Afterlife", and "Dark Rain".

Has anyone worked out how many different universes would be required to accommodate every episode of The Outer Limits?

Comment: But do we have any indication that it couldn't have been the same universe throughout? I mean, for example all those invading alien spaceships, although so prominently displayed on our TV screens, were most probably not visible from most places on Earth, so the majority of people never even noticed anything, being to busy as they were fighting off ghosts, swamp monsters etc.

Comment: And of course by "invading" I mean "visiting", "crashing" etc.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to answer, because a lot of the universes could coexist, and even in the clip shows they sometimes twist the context of the original clips into new storylines, turn something that was supernatural and imply it was aliens, for example.  Are they wrong?  Or does the same events happen in a couple different universes?

Comment: @MrLister "1" is certainly a possible answer :)

Comment: @starpilotsix I agree. You could maybe chalk some of those up to unreliable narration, but an answer that sets a lower and upper bound to this might be the closest we can get (without Word of God or something).